# Need to add Static Text to PHP Email Body that uses foreach

Tags: php

I'm using a simple formmail.php file. I've been asked to insert text in the top of the body of every email that says

> "You have been sent this request for a Pool estimate from the
>   www.mydomain.com website. Please respond to this lead within 24 hours.
>
> Thank you"

Here is my code. Can anyone tell me how to insert this before the `foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) $body .= $key . ": " . $val ."\r\n"`;

```
header("Access-Control-Request-Method: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:DELETE');
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

    // first validate the dealer email - if we didn't get a valid email address, return an error
    if (!eregi("^[+_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$", trim($_POST['Email'])))
    {
        echo "That is not a valid email address. Please return to the previous page and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // build email body



    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) $body .= $key . ": " . $val ."\r\n";


    // you can specify which email you want your contact form to be emailed to here
    $toemail = "getafreeestimate@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Request a Pool Estimate";

    $headers  = "From: " . $_POST['FirstName'] . " " . $_POST['LastName'] . "< " . trim($_POST['Email']) . " >/r/n";
    $headers .= "Subject: Dealer Estimate Request/r/n";
    $headers .= "Cc: " . $_POST['DealerName'] . " < " . trim($_POST['DealerEmail']) . " >/r/n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0/r/n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1/r/n";


    mail($toemail, $subject, $body, $headers);

    echo "Message sent";
?>
```

Would like my final email body to look something like this:

> You have been sent this request for a Pool estimate from the
>   www.mydomain.com website.
>
> Please respond to this lead within 24 hours.
>
> Thank you
>
> DealerName: My Favorite Dealer  DealerEmail:  dealer@yahoo.com 
>   DealerAddress: main st. Anywhere, MA  123456  FirstName: tesst 
>   LastName: two  Phone: 1234567890  Email: someone@gmail.com  Zip: 12345
>   budget: $50,000 +  Message: test for body message

Answer (score 0):

you can use variable increment in foreach loop. 
here is your re structured foreach loop.

### [LIVE CODE EXAMPLE WORKING](https://eval.in/1100064)

```
$i = 0;
$body = '';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {

    if ($i == 0) {
        // first
       $body .= "You have been sent this request for a Pool estimate from the 
                  www.mydomain.com website.  \r\n
                 Please respond to this lead within 24 hours. \r\n
                 Thank you \r\n";
    } 
    $body .= $key . ": " . $val ."\r\n";

    $i++;// incrementing in loop
}
```

or if you want u can set it outside loop like below

### [LIVE CODE EXAMPLE 2 WORKING](https://eval.in/1100065)

```
 $body= ''; 
 if(isset($_POST)){
  $body .= "You have been sent this request for a Pool estimate from the 
                  www.mydomain.com website.  \r\n
                 Please respond to this lead within 24 hours. \r\n
                 Thank you \r\n";
   foreach ($_POST as $key => $val){ $body .= $key . ": " . $val ."\r\n";}
 }
```

NOTE: if you want to use html in body text u can replace your body string like below

```
$body .= "<p> You have been sent this request for a Pool estimate from the 
                  www.mydomain.com website.  </br></br>
                 Please respond to this lead within 24 hours. </br></br>
                 Thank you </br></br> </p>";
$body .= $key . ": " . $val ."</br>";
```

Comment: So I tried the first example provided.  The email does not send using this code:

Comment: In all three cases I simply replaced my code lines as follows with yours. Am I missing something?

Comment: lines I replaced:// build email body
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) $body .= $key . ": " . $val ."\r\n";

Comment: I have updated my code with example link. please check

Comment: Please note that HTML body is expected.

Comment: @Raptor ok as ur suggestion I also suggested how to place html on body

Comment: Tanks so much for all of your help.  It is GREATLY APPRECIATED

Comment: @ImperialPools Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer [(see How to accept SO answers)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) and upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you [(see How to upvote on Stack Overflow?)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a variable and set it to `false` after using once:

```
$first = true;
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if ($first) {
        $body .= "You have been sent this request for a Pool estimate from the 
                  www.mydomain.com website.  \r\n
                  Please respond to this lead within 24 hours. \r\n
                  Thank you \r\n";
        $first = false;
    } 
    $body .= $key . ": " . $val ."\r\n";
}
```

Comment: My apologies.....I just tried this again and it is working!  Thank you so, so much!

Comment: Wait. The code is problematic. You use `text/html` as content encoding, but the email body is in plain text. The first few lines of `header()` are unnecessary as well.